# getting users on my radius via geofire to a list and rules

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, geofire

so to this points im facing 2 problems,
first one is

> Using an unspecified index. Consider adding '".indexOn": "g"' at
>   Geofire to your security and Firebase Database rules for better
>   performance

while running the app
those are my securety rules via firebase

```
{
  "rules": {
    ".read": "auth != null",
    ".write": "auth != null"
  }
}
```

this is my database[image]

second question, im trying to get the number of users on my radius except me, for some reason , im finding only one eventhough on the database theres are 2 at the location , and radius is 100km, here example of the code, please help me

```
final Set<String> runnersNearby = new HashSet<String>();

geoFire.setLocation(uid, new GeoLocation(lat, lang));

GeoQuery geoQuery = geoFire.queryAtLocation(new GeoLocation(lat, lang), radius);
geoQuery.addGeoQueryEventListener(new GeoQueryEventListener() {
    @Override
    public void onKeyEntered(String key, GeoLocation location) {
        Toast.makeText(UserProfile.this, "Successfully Found", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        if (key != user.getUid())
            runnersNearby.add(key);
        Log.d("Number of users", String.valueOf(runnersNearby.size()));
        Log.d("KEY", String.valueOf(key));
    }

    @Override
    public void onKeyExited(String key) {
        Toast.makeText(UserProfile.this, "left the place", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        runnersNearby.remove(key);
    }

    @Override
    public void onKeyMoved(String key, GeoLocation location) {
        Toast.makeText(UserProfile.this, "key moved but here", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }

    @Override
    public void onGeoQueryReady() {
        System.out.println("All initial data has been loaded and events have been fired!");
    }

    @Override
    public void onGeoQueryError(DatabaseError error) {
        Toast.makeText(UserProfile.this, "Error Occured", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
});
```

Comment: for your second question, the code is fine. looks like the other user is just too far away (more than 100km), try adding the radius or try to calculate the distance manually from all users to your current location.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The message is pretty explicit:

```
{
  "rules": {
    ".read": "auth != null",
    ".write": "auth != null",
    "Geofire": {
      ".indexOn": "g"
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks mate! any idea about the second issue?

Answer (score 0):

1- saving location to firebase: geoFire.setlocation......

2- query location from firebase: getlocationforkey.....

a- query by region geoFire.querybyregion(region)   you need to declare region with coordinate in mapKit.

b- observing events:
1- ObserveEventType(.keyEntered....)

2- .................(.keyExited....)